# SharePoint 2010 Populate Lookup Field on Activation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two lists: [Parents] [Children]. The Children list has a one-to-one lookup column to the Parents list. When deploying the Children List I have data written into the  tag using

```
<Data>
 <Rows>
  <Row>
   <Field Name="ChildName">Stephanie</Field>
   <Field Name="ParentNameLookup">What value goes here?</Field>
  </Row>
 </Rows>
</Data>
```

My question: is there a way to populate the data into the  tag for the ParentNameLookup field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<Field Name="ParentNameLookup">ID;#VALUE</Field>
```

Where ID is ID of the Parent List Item and VALUE Represents actual Text.

Comment: Both lists are being created in the same feature. It is my understanding that they won't have ID's until after activation, which is too late for data population. Could I use the URL or something else instead of the ID?

Comment: @Greg : Feature Handler is a Good Option for this kind of Cases then. But belive me I had exact same case, what I did was ugly but it works, I know for sure this is going to be a new list and id starts from 1, I added Data based on that assumption and it works. There is no validation .